# Generics as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why `go` method gives me a compile time exception even if `Animal` is parent class of `Dog` ?

```
class Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}

class Sample { 
    void go(ArrayList<Animal> list){}   

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
       ArrayList<Dog> list=new ArrayList<Dog>();
       new Sample().go(list);
    }
}
```

This gives me a compile time error why?

Comment: A mutable list of `Animal` can have more operations performed on it than a mutable list of `Dog` (for example, inserting `Animal`s that are not `Dog`s), and therefore `ArrayList<Dog>` is not a valid subtype of `ArrayList<Animal>`.

Comment: @Mankarse: this should be an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a bit unintuitive, generic is not covariance in Java.

Which means, even `Dog` `is-an` `Animal`, `List<Dog>` is NOT a `List<Animal>`.  (However `Dog[]` `is-an` `Animal[]`, just to further confuse you LOL ).

Normal way to deal with the problem is to make use of wildcard in generics, for example, change your `go()` to `void go(List<? extends Animal> list){}`.

Answer (score 0):

As Mankarse stated:

> A mutable list of `Animal` can have more operations performed on it than a mutable list of `Dog` (for example, inserting `Animal`s that are not `Dog`s), and therefore `ArrayList<Dog>` is not a valid subtype of `ArrayList<Animal>`.

This is a general characteristic of generics, as the rules of normal inheritance dont apply on generic type parameters. A more detailed explanation on this [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).

To circumvent this problem, you can use generic wildcards. For example a method with the signature `perform(List<? extends Animal> animals)` allows passing a list with a generic type parameter of anything that extends `Animal` - for example `Dog`.

On the other side `perform(List<Animal> animals)` only allows passing a list with the `Animal` type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Generics restrict you to pass only same type of parameter that define in method definition. Below solution will work for you.

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

`class Animal{}`

`class Dog extends Animal{}`

`public class Sample {`

`void go(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list){}`

`public static void main(String...args)`
   `{`

`ArrayList<Dog> list=new ArrayList<Dog>();`
     `new Sample().go(list);`
 `}}`

Answer (score -1):

As Mankarse already pointed out, you cannot let `ArrayList<Animal>` be a supertype of `ArrayList<Dog>` since it allows inserting elements.

If you would use a read-only collection/interface (don't know what this would be in java), then it should be possible.